# A Wiki using flat files and a mobile app?

Tags: android, cms, note-taking, wiki, static-site-generator

For my workflow, I'm looking for a combination of features in a note taking system that I am having some trouble finding (I might just be looking in the wrong places).  These are:

1. I have a lot of content scattered in many small or large notes, so a hierarchical tagging system is very useful.  Wiki-type interfaces seem good for this.
2. Flat text file based for easy backups, version control, future-proofness and content adding / editing from a Linux based desktop system. Please no propietary solutions like Evernote etc. (aaargh) :).
3. Content that can be edited / added via an Android app (preferably not through the browser) of some kind.

It does not need to create a publicly available website (it's only for my own use).  It doesn't even need to be a hosted solution - it could be a software that uses syncing, though the latter does face the problem of conflicts.

I used to use [Tiddlywiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/), which met requirements 1 and 2 very well (especially after I wrote a Bash script that made command line based editing easy), but of course failed at 3.  Recently I have shifted to [Simplenote](https://simplenote.com/) which is brilliant at 2 and 3 (in combination with [sncli](https://github.com/insanum/sncli)) but fails at 1.

I'm wondering about flat file CMSs like Grav, but I'm not sure how to meet requirement 3 - easy mobile editing.

Am I just looking in the wrong places?

Comment: I cannot recommend any as I have not used any, but be welcome to take a look at my app listing on [Editors for Wikis](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_106). It has some candidates with desktop pendants. If Markdown is acceptable, continue that page to the next section :)

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Markdown is certainly acceptable - actually the main formatting tool I use these days.  The problem is that most of those apps use their own format, except for WikiMind, and it hasn't been updated in forever.  I'm scared re future-proofness :)

Comment: Then pick a Markdown editor? At least the "base format" (standard markdown) is clearly defined. Using extensions (Github-/SE-flavored or Markdown Extra) is a different thing, of course, though those are pretty much standard as well.

Comment: I'm already doing that - Simplenote includes a built in markdown editor, and unlike a plain editor it offers syncing and it is cross-platform.  But as said the problem is one of hierarchical classification to easily categorise a large number (>2500) of notes, which Simplenote doesn't offer.